Highcharts in Angular 19 throwing SSR console error
I've got a simple highchart drawing a pie chart in the UI and everything is working well but the console is getting plagued with this error whenever rendering my chart. Is there something I can do to fix this?
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createEvent')
at j (C:\Users\mg\Dev\challenge\.angular\cache\19.0.2\challenge\vite\deps_ssr\highcharts.js:168:32)
at aR.init (C:\Users\mg\Dev\challenge\.angular\cache\19.0.2\challenge\vite\deps_ssr\highcharts.js:6533:11)
at new aR (C:\Users\mg\Dev\challenge\.angular\cache\19.0.2\challenge\vite\deps_ssr\highcharts.js:6520:76)
at Object.chart (C:\Users\mg\Dev\challenge\.angular\cache\19.0.2\challenge\vite\deps_ssr\highcharts.js:6515:18)
at _HighchartsChartComponent.updateOrCreateChart (C:\Users\mgrac\Dev\challenge\.angular\cache\19.0.2\challenge\vite\deps_ssr\highcharts-angular.js:50:68)
at _HighchartsChartComponent.wrappedUpdateOrCreateChart (C:\Users\mg\Dev\challenge\.angular\cache\19.0.2\challenge\vite\deps_ssr\highcharts-angular.js:43:12)
at _HighchartsChartComponent.ngOnChanges (C:\Users\mg\Dev\challenge\.angular\cache\19.0.2\challenge\vite\deps_ssr\highcharts-angular.js:31:12)
at _HighchartsChartComponent.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (C:\Users\mg\Dev\challenge\.angular\cache\19.0.2\challenge\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-NONX6MLK.js:3696:10)
at callHookInternal (C:\Users\mg\Dev\challenge\.angular\cache\19.0.2\challenge\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-NONX6MLK.js:4282:10)
at callHook (C:\Users\mg\Dev\challenge\.angular\cache\19.0.2\challenge\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-NONX6MLK.js:4300:5)

My component TS
import { HighchartsChartModule } from 'highcharts-angular';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-progress-chart',
  imports: [CommonModule, HighchartsChartModule],
  templateUrl: './progress-chart.component.html',
  styleUrl: './progress-chart.component.css'
})
export class ProgressChartComponent {

  isHighcharts = typeof Highcharts === 'object';
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options =  {...}

My component HTML
<highcharts-chart
    *ngIf="isHighCharts"
    [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
    [options]="chartOptions">
</highcharts-chart>```


The problem is that the code from highcharts angular is using either document or window object which is available only on the browser and not on the server, hence you are getting the error.

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createEvent')


For now you can temporarily fix the issue by wrapping the component inside a defer block so that the content renders only on the browser.
@defer {
    <highcharts-chart
        [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
        [options]="chartOptions">
    </highcharts-chart>
}

The best solution is to fix it on the library, I have raise a bug #393 - SSR Documentation inaccurate for highcharts angular as well as the fix for the bug PR-394 - #393 - highcharts ssr compatibility angular which I think is the correct fix.
Until that get's completed you can use this fix which works great.
@defer {
  <highcharts-chart
    [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
    [options]="chartOptions"
    style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;"
  ></highcharts-chart>
}

Stackblitz Demo
